# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404, with the read_html function

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, xml2

I got the following error when using the `read_html` function from the xml2 package:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
```

Here is the URL I attempted to read:

```
xml2::read_html("https://www.act.is/media-centre/press-releases/actis-energy-platform-zuma-energía-reaches-financial-close-on-two-further-solar-farms-in-mexico/")
```

By contrast, no error was generated when reading this URL

```
xml2::read_html("https://www.act.is/media-centre/press-releases/actis-wins-cio-magazine-s-real-asset-award/")
```

The first URL contains a word with an accent mark "energía", the second URL does not.
Is it possible to read URLs containing words with accent marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're special characters in the URL and you have to escape them. In Python there's HTTP libraries for that, for the R you can find [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/vignettes/urltools.html)

Python expamle:

```
base_url = "https://www.act.is/media-centre/press-releases/"
encoded_url = requests.utils.quote("actis-energy-platform-zuma-energía-reaches-financial-close-on-two-further-solar-farms-in-mexico/")
response = requests.get(base_url + encoded_url)
```

Encoded URL:

> https://www.act.is/media-centre/press-releases/actis-energy-platform-zuma-energ%C3%ADa-reaches-financial-close-on-two-further-solar-farms-in-mexico/

Comment: If the answer was helpful you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)